# AppleScriptObjC: Can't create AVMIDIPlayer object

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I'm having some trouble with a bit of AppleScript ObjC code. The problem line seems to be when I initialize the AVMIDIPlayer object (3rd line of repeat). It comes back with a -1 error, (AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusError). The next line then fails, because a Nil object doesn't have any methods.

Here's the relevant bits:

```
property NSURL : a reference to current application's NSURL
property AVMIDIPlayer : a reference to current application's AVMIDIPlayer
on open (filelist)
    repeat with each_item in filelist
        set myfile to quoted form of POSIX path of each_item as string
        set myMIDIFile to (NSURL's fileURLWithPath:myfile)
        set {myMIDIPlayer, theError} to (AVMIDIPlayer's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfURL:myMIDIFile soundBankURL:none |error|:(reference))
        myMIDIPlayer's prepareToPlay()
        myMIDIPlayer's play(myHandler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the issue is `quoted form of`.

Use it **only** in `do shell script` lines to escape string containing spaces and special characters, nowhere else.

```
set myfile to POSIX path of each_item -- no coercion: POSIX path is string
```

And handle `theError`

Comment: Thanks. I had to make a few other adjustments, too, but that seems to have helped.